# Run iPhone simulator with appiume but get xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message:

Tags: automated-testing, appium, test-strategy, mobile-automation

I'm using `Appium` to run an `iPhone simulator` and it's not working.

I got the following `error message`:

```
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message:
```

Here is my `Desired Capabilities`:

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "appium:platformVersion": "16.0",
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 14 Pro",
  "appium:app": "com.apple.mobileslideshow"
}
```

I want to run some `test automation` via the simulator in `Appium`, but I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong or maybe I don't get how the use `Appium` to run the simulator.

Any help or explanation is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the significant challenge faced by a software testing company or engineers while setting up iOS Automation via Appium.

Common reason for the Appium launch failing with the specified reason is the WebDriverAgent not configured properly before launching the app via Appium .

1. For this, WebDriverAgent needs to be executed once on the iOS Simulator device before running tests
2. Please run the WebDriverAgent Xcode project which is located here on your Mac:
   `/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj`
3. In this Xcode project follow the below steps to build the WebDriverAgentRunner:

- Select the WebDriverAgentRunner as active Scheme
- Select the iPhone Simulator.
- Make sure the runner is signed and Select your team under ‘Signing & Capabilities’ settings of the project
- Build and Run the  WebDriverAgentRunner runner on simulator by selecting Product > Test from the Xcode menu’s bar
- Once Runner is successfully installed on the device, Simulator is ready for launching the app via appium

Comment: Hi Vishal, thanks for your help, i made it! and I find that only can install .app file at simulator, but our team usually give .ipa file to us, so I can't do automation at simulator device